# How to make a unique sequence number in Neo4j?

Tags: java, neo4j, thread-safety

I am writing an unmanaged extension.

Since Neo4J do not have any built in functionality to get a sequence number I wrote this method to achieve something like it. It works fine with the "synchronized" keyword, but without it I got an DeadlockDetectedException when trying to use it in a testcase where I call it from multiple threads at the same time.

Is this a good way to solve this problem?

Why do I need to make the method "synchronized", shouldn't the "acquireReadLock" be enough?

```java
public synchronized static int getNextSequence(Node node, String property) {
    int sequence = 0;
    GraphDatabaseService graphDb = node.getGraphDatabase();

    try(Transaction t = graphDb.beginTx()) {
        t.acquireReadLock(node);

        sequence = (int) node.getProperty(property);
        node.setProperty(property, sequence + 1);

        //The lock is automatic released on t.success().
        t.success();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Failed to get sequence for node: ({}), property: ({}), exception: ({})", node, property, e);
        throw e;
    }

    return sequence;
}
```

**EDIT**
After response from @cybersam I changed acquireReadLock to acquireWriteLock which solved the DeadlockProblem problem and I no longer need to make the method synchronized.

The updated code looks like this:

```java
public static int getNextSequence(Node node, String property) {
    int sequence = 0;
    GraphDatabaseService graphDb = node.getGraphDatabase();

    try(Transaction t = graphDb.beginTx()) {
        t.acquireWriteLock(node);

        sequence = (int) node.getProperty(property);
        node.setProperty(property, sequence + 1);

        //The lock is automatic released on t.success().
        t.success();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Failed to get sequence for node: ({}), property: ({}), exception: ({})", node, property, e);
        throw e;
    }

    return sequence;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is actually writing to (as well as reading from) the node, but you are only acquiring a read lock. You must use [acquireWriteLock](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/Transaction.html#acquireWriteLock-org.neo4j.graphdb.PropertyContainer-) instead. Once you do so, you should get rid of "synchronized" (see the warning in [this section of the docs](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/#transactions-deadlocks)).